# Gridview popup window not opening from RowCommand event corresponding to Linkbutton click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, rowcommand

I have Linkbutton in the Gridview TemplateField. 
I want to Redirect to another Page in a popup Custom size window from RowCommand Event.

**Note:** Here I don't want to call OnClientScript property of LinkButton to openJavascript Popup Custom Size Window. I want to save Gridrow into Session object and open window from Serverside code only.

**Here is the Code:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <itemstyle width="5%" />
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link" ID="lnkView" runat="server"  
      DataTextField="overWriteType" 
      CommandName="overWriteType"
      CommandArgument='<%# Eval("overWriteType") %>'
      Text='<%# Eval("overWriteType") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```cs
protected void gvKeys_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "overWriteType")
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("&lt;script language='javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.open('OverwriteConfiguration.aspx', 'PopUp',");
        sb.Append("'top=0, left=0, width=500, height=500, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status,resizable=yes,addressbar=no');<");
        sb.Append("/script>");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "OpenWindow", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

The above code is not opening any window.

Comment: Isn't it an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use RegisterStartupScript in this case, you want to add an onclick handler for your button and you want to do it in RowDataBound instead:

```
protected void gvKeys_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {

    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("window.open('OverwriteConfiguration.aspx', 'PopUp',");
    sb.Append("'top=0, left=0, width=500, height=500, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status,resizable=yes,addressbar=no');<");

    LinkButton l = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkView");

    l.Attributes.Add("onclick", sb.ToString());

   }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean in RowDataBound event?